# Faulty output because of Polyglossia issue

Tags: miktex, compiling, hyphenation, polyglossia

this is my first question on here so I hope I'll include all necessary information right away.
I am running MiKTeX 2.9, set up for XeTeX; my Editor is TeXMaker and my OS is Windows 8, 64-bit.

Yesterday (Feb 13, 2013) I ran an update through MiKTeX's update wizard, as a consequence the `miktex-runtime-bin-2.9` got updated which caused all sorts of trouble (mostly no package being detected anymore). I reinstalled MiKTeX except for the faulty, `miktex-runtime-bin-2.9`. All packages (at least all I use regularly) work fine, except for polyglossia.

A code example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, numbers=noendperiod, listof=numberedtotoc]{scrreprt}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

An output is produced, but with the following error messages:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>  \l@german 
l.7 \select@language {german}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>  \l@german 
l.22 \begin{document}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

Package polyglossia Warning: You asked for `ngerman' but only
`german' hyphenation is available! on input line 48.
```

As a result, the hyphenation does not work anymore, especially not in the references (not for the code I put in the example; that's just a short version to show which packages I use).

Polyglossia was working fine before I updated `miktex-runtime-bin-2.9`, therefore I have no idea why these errors are issued, also because I properly set the default languages.
I consulted the Polyglossia documentary and also checked for a similar question, if it was asked somewhere else; however I could not find a working answer, especially because the issue is quite recent. I should also note, that the same code with the same versions of MiKTeX and Polyglossia is working without problems on my other computer.

I hope this was not too long of a read. If you require more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: There seems to be quite a number of messages around the net about the last update to MiKTeX corrupting the list of preloaded languages. The reference to `ngerman` is quite strange, however.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It looks like you did most of the work towards a good MWE, but I would assume many of the packages you’re using have nothing to do with the problem. Please have a look at my advice here and simplify your code (you can [edit] the question): [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225)

Comment: Okay, I just trimmed down the example a little bit. @egreg Especially that mentioning of `ngerman` completely puzzles me. Maybe I'll just have to wait for a fix to `miktex-runtime-bin-2.9`; hopefully that'll straighten up `polyglossia` as well.

Comment: You may be able to find something at the MiKTeX mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=miktex-users

Comment: The warning is imho a bug in polyglossia: It inadvertendly defines `\l@german` to `\relax` (problably due to an `\csname...\endcsname`) and so a test ends in the wrong branch. The main problem is that the hyphenation patterns are not in the format - and this is perhaps due to a broken local `language.ini`.

Comment: Okay, I feel like I'm running out of options. During the last days I reinstalled MiKTeX completely, also uninstalled and reinstalled `polyglossia` through the package manager, and just now I copied the entire MiKTeX directory from the other computer where it is working onto this computer. Still the same errors.

Comment: Any other suggestions on what I could try? Also sorry for the double post; hit the enter button a bit prematurely, I'm afraid.

Comment: For texlive i had to install `texlive-lang-german` package on debian

Answer (score 0):

With an update in similar dates, using MikTeX 2.9, I discovered that all the languages were gone.  It was imposible to download all the languages and rebuild the index file.  Therefore I restored from a back up.

Discovered that some downloaded files get a 'protected' status, and probably that is causing the failure.